# Adobe CQ - fetch HTML content from .jsp node

Tags: html, jsp, adobe, aem

Have `.jsp` file under `/components`

path looks like: 
 `http://localhost:4502/apps/project-name/components/my-component/one.jsp`

Is it possible get `HTML` content of this `one.jsp` by url without creating content node?

something like:

```
http://localhost:4502/apps/project-name/components/my-component/one.HTML
```

the `.html` content is needed for further rendering.

Comment: IIUC "the .html content is needed for further rendering" means that the HTML that your JSP is generating is meant to be included in another page. In this case you're better off using a <cq:include> JSP tag which includes the rendering of a resource. That would target a Sling resource (content or other node) of course. You can also include JSP's in other JSP's as usual using @include.

Comment: Hi Bertrand, I see your point. One more clarification to be more detailed: this .html should be invoked on click on link (like `<a href="this.html"/>`)I mean that it would be reference to html content of jsp within other jsp page.

Comment: Ok so for this the recommended way is really to create a content node, if only to make sure access control is handled properly. You don't want your users to read JSPs in general, so putting the actual content somewhere else than under /apps is the recommended way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, you cannot get the html content from the JSP directly by providing the path to the jsp file. It displays the content in the JSP as is without compiling.

One possible way is to create an nt:unstructured node with the sling:resourceType property set to the path of the jsp (something like below)

```
test: {
    sling:resourceType: "/apps/geometrixx/components/title/one.jsp",
    jcr:primaryType: "nt:unstructured"
}
```

And you can provide the path to the test node to get the html rendered by the jsp.

```
/apps/geometrixx/components/title/test
```

Comment: hi, thank you for answer, such approach causes error for me: Guice injector name not available.

Comment: @sergionni Are you using Slice framework ? The above example works in my server(doesnt have slice). Could you provide more information regarding the error so that we can figure it out?

Comment: yes, Sling. the error looks like: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Guice injector name not available
 at com.cognifide.slice.api.tag.SliceTagUtils.getFromCurrentPath(SliceTagUtils.java:73)` ...

Comment: looks like `appName` parameter from method `SliceTagUtils.getFromCurrentPath` is blank.What does this param mean?

Comment: @sergionni please check this link https://cognifide.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4128820. They are trying to get the appName property specified in the <slice:lookup>, and if not specified, it checks for the "injectorName" property in the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but as far as i get it, you want to retrieve the html for the whole page which can be done by reading the input stream from a URL using java.net.URL utility.

May be you can also place an iframe inside your other jsp to get the contents.

Comment: i just want express .jsp as pure .html without creating node under content hierarchy, in order to acces this .jsp like: /one.html or some other similar way

Comment: No backend, just get html content by url, the question, is what url should be used. Thank you for assistance.

Comment: As i said you can use the URL utility for reading the contents of jsp as is.[Here is a link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) for the same.

The url you will supply in this can come from [Externalizer](http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/com.day.cq.commons.impl.ExternalizerImpl). Refer Api methods of Externalizer publishLink //authorLink // absoluteLink. Externalizer can be used to configure links for various environments.

Comment: i mean, can I get .html view like: `/http://localhost:4502/apps/project-name/components/my-component/one.jsp/jcr:content/jcr:data` or somethig other way?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a traditional .html file instead of a .jsp, but (perhaps obviously) you will lose all the server side capabilities afforded by JSP.

It is also worth noting that anonymous access is typically denied to /apps for security reasons, so this .html file would not be reachable on a publish instance with OOTB permissions.