# AEM unable to access jsp from url

Tags: jsp, aem

I created a JSP file directly via CRX into my website. The target is to access it via a direct url instead of a separate template. Example:

```
http://localhost:4502/content/mywebsite/somepage/test.jsp
```

But the browser just gives me option to download it instead of opening and processing the jsp and the code inside it.
I cannot use an HTML file as I need to run some Java code in this JSP.

Comment: Why not just use a `Servlet`?

Comment: Why do you want to run code without an output (HTML)? Anyway, you can look at https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/aem-fiddle/index.html to see how some fiddling can be done. AEM is not really designed to run just simple JSP. Like @Jens said, use a servlet instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to render a script directly in Sling. Hence, if you try to access one, you would either see the uncompiled JSP output or it would provide the JSP as a downloadable resource.

A more elaborate explanation for the same can be found at  [How to render a simple JSP page in CQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300012/how-to-render-a-simple-jsp-page-in-cq/25300311#25300311) and [Adobe CQ - fetch HTML content from .jsp node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912078/adobe-cq-fetch-html-content-from-jsp-node/19923049#19923049)